# XCode 7 : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

[image]

```
Ld /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.app/UsingSegue normal i386
    cd "/Users/Abhinav/Desktop/Fist Project/UsingSegue"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk
-L/Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-filelist /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Intermediates/UsingSegue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.build/Objects-normal/i386/UsingSegue.LinkFileList
-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Intermediates/UsingSegue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.build/Objects-normal/i386/UsingSegue_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.app/UsingSegue

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_NextViewController._NextArray in:
    /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Intermediates/UsingSegue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Intermediates/UsingSegue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.build/Objects-normal/i386/NextViewController.o duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_NextViewController in:
    /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Intermediates/UsingSegue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Intermediates/UsingSegue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.build/Objects-normal/i386/NextViewController.o duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NextViewController in:
    /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Intermediates/UsingSegue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/Abhinav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UsingSegue-bujjpyciairreubqxbgfqixpwbiv/Build/Intermediates/UsingSegue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsingSegue.build/Objects-normal/i386/NextViewController.o ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have checked my Compile Sources, there are no duplicates there , still I am getting this error.
I am new to IOS , someone please help.
I am trying to create array in a View Controller and then pass it to another view controller using segues.

ViewController.m :

```
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
    {
    self.ArrayInput = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.ArrayInput addObject:@[_firstname.text]];
    [self.ArrayInput addObject:@[_lastname.text]];
    [self.ArrayInput addObject:@[_Email.text]];

NextViewController * nextcontroller = (NextViewController *)[self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextcontroller animated:YES];

}
```

Then using segue in ViewController.m:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NextViewController * NextVC = (NextViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
NextVC.NextArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.ArrayInput];

}
```

NextViewController.m:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.Data.text = [self.NextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this error often happens is accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h

**OR**

**Steps:**

1. Check Build phases in Target settings.
2. Check if any file exists twice or once.
3. If file exist twice delete one.

Comment: checked my code again.. had declared nsmutablearray in NextViewController.m... had to create the array in NextViewController.h and included  the NextViewController.h file in ViewController.m.. resolved my issue.. thanks..

Answer (score -1):

checked my code again.. had declared nsmutablearray in NextViewController.m... had to create the array in NextViewController.h and included the NextViewController.h file in ViewController.m.. resolved my issue.. thanks.